# Banach isomorphisms between von Neumann algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It seems that most people are talking about $*$-isomorphisms of von Neumann algebras. However, I can not find any references for the Banach isomorphisms, i.e., let $A,B$ be two different von Neumann algebras (consider them as Banach spaces equipped with uniform norms), are there any bijective mapping from $A$ onto $B$? In particular, I would like to consider the case when $A$ is a finite von Neumann algebra and $B=B(H)$.

I have posted this question in stackexchange but I think it fits mathoverflow more.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4717820/banach-isomorphisms-between-von-neumann-algebras

Comment: To clarify: is the question whether or not there is a bounded linear bijective function $f:A\to B$?

Comment: All non-subhomogeneous injective von Neumann algebras with separable predual (including the hyperfinite II_1 factor and $B(\ell_2)$) are Banach isomorphic by Pelczynski's decomposition method. On the other hand, I'm not sure if there is any non-injective von Neumann algebra that is Banach isomorphic to $B(\ell_2)$. See Rosenthal's survey for a relevant literature.  http://www.ams.org/books/conm/321/5650/conm321-5650.pdf

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA The paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.13743 of Pisier says that certain non-injective vN algebras are isomorphic as Banach spaces to $B(\ell_2)$, via some non-cb complementation maps and the usual Pelczynski decomposition machine

Comment: @Yemon Choi: Thanks! I should have remembered it.

Comment: Please see Theorem 1 in https://doi.org/10.1093/qmath/41.4.449

Comment: Not exactly the question itself but related: Theorem 7 in https://doi.org/10.2307/1969534 implies that if two $C^*$-algebras are *isometrically* isomorphic as Banach spaces, then they are Jordan $*$-isomorphic. In particular, for von Neumann factors this implies that they are either $*$-isomorphic or $*$-anti-isomorphic. So if you are asking about isometric isomorphisms, then no, $B(l^2)$ is not isometrically isomorphic to any finite vNa as Banach spaces.